# D3 JS: Create a page index.html to run the js project

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I downloaded this project from github https://github.com/mcaule/d3-timeseries , but I don't know how to run this project to display the d3 graph. There are examples in this site: http://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/.
For example I was thinking of writing a html page to run the project but I don't know how.

Comment: That's because there is no documentation.

Comment: There are however, some examples here: http://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/.

Comment: @Danny By "I was thinking of writing a html page to run this project" do you mean you want to know how to load it into a html file? Like this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YjWpdz?editors=1000

Comment: @REEE Yes ,I want to know to load it into a html file.I don't want links http but the file paths of downloaded project.

Answer (score 2):

A working prototype for you -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/d3_timeseries.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/d3_timeseries.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/create-example-data.js"></script>
    <section class="main-content">
        <h3>
            Difference
        </h3>

        <!-- <div class="chartContainer"> -->
            <!-- <p class="codepen" data-default-tab="result" data-embed-version="2" data-height="500" data-pen-title="d3-timeseries Example 1" data-slug-hash="wPpJWr" data-theme-id="dark" data-user="mcaule"> -->
            <div id="chart"></div>
            <!-- </p> -->
            <script>
                var data = createRandomData(80,[0,1000],0.01)
                // [{date:new Date('2013-01-01'),n:120,n3:200,ci_up:127,ci_down:115},...]
                var chart = d3_timeseries()
                  .addSerie(data.slice(0,60),{x:'date',y:'n'},{interpolate:'linear',color:"#a6cee3",label:"value"})
                  .addSerie(data.slice(50),
                          {x:'date',y:'n3',ci_up:'ci_up',ci_down:'ci_down'},
                          {interpolate:'monotone',dashed:true,color:"#a6cee3",label:"prediction"})
                  .width(820)

                chart('#chart')
            </script>
        <!-- </div> -->
    </section>
</body>
```

copy it as it is and paste it in an .html file then open that file in browser, everything would be working perfectly fine, and if it is not then please let me know.

Comment: It works but I want the file paths of downloaded project instead of links http.

Comment: for that, what you have to do is, in the same folder in which you have kept the .html file that I have provided above keep all downloaded file and reference them, for example, if file name is **index.js**, then reference it as **<scritpt src="./index.js"></script>**, hope this might help, and if you find my answer helpful then do upvote it.

Comment: You use the files of the folder "dist", why are not there any files of the folder "src"?

Comment: it doesn't matter, you can use the file of folder src too instead of folder dist, they both contains the same code, but I preferred files of dist folder over src folder because it contains minified version of the same file which is more faster to load for browser as compared to regular files.

Comment: If my answer is right, then mark it as right, which will show a green tick.

Comment: My question was not completely answered, because if I use regular files instead of min files it does not work. I need to use regular files and not min ones.

Comment: then you must be doing something wrong while giving the path of the file, because it doesn't matter for compiler or interpreter whether a file is minified or not, the files are ran and evaluated in exactly the same.

Comment: can you share the code with me and also the hierarchy of your files.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone need to add this graph to React, you can do the following.

1. In the idex.html file, import the necessary files

```
...
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/d3_timeseries.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.10.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/dist/d3_timeseries.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

2. Then create the React component

```
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import React from "react";

var frenchLocale = d3.timeFormatLocale({
    "dateTime": "%a %e %b %Y %X",
    "date": "%d-%m-%Y",
    "time": "%Hh%M",
    "periods": ["am", "pm"],
    "days": ["Dimanche","Lundi", "Mardi", "Mercredi", "Jeudi", "Vendredi", "Samedi"],
    "shortDays": ["Dim", "Lun", "Mar", "Mer", "Jeu", "Ven", "Sam"],
    "months": ["Janvier", "Février", "Mars", "Avril", "Mai", "Juin", "Juillet", "Aôut", "Septembre", "Octobre", "Novembre", "Décembre"],
    "shortMonths": ["Jan", "Fév", "Mar", "Avr", "Mai", "Juin", "Juil", "Aôut", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Déc"]
  })
  
var frenchTimeFormat = function(date){
return (
    d3.timeDay(date) < date ? frenchLocale.format("%Hh") :
    d3.timeMonth(date) < date ? frenchLocale.format("%d/%m") :
    d3.timeYear(date) < date ? frenchLocale.format("%B") :
    d3.timeFormat("%Y")
)(date)
}
// this function can also import as above, in the index.html file, if you do not need to edit it.
function createRandomData(n, range, rand) {
    if (range == null) range = [0, 100];
    if (rand == null) rand = 1 / 200;
  
    var num = range[0] + Math.floor(Math.random() * (range[1] - range[0]));
    var num2 = range[0] + Math.floor(Math.random() * (range[1] - range[0]));
    var num3 = num;
    var d = new Date("2013-01-01");
    var data = [];
    var rgen = d3.randomNormal(0, (range[1] - range[0]) * rand);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      data.push({
        date: d,
        n: num,
        n2: num2,
        n3: num3,
        ci_up: num3 * 1.05,
        ci_down: num3 * 0.95
      });
      d = new Date(d.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
      num = num + rgen();
      num3 = num + rgen() / 3;
      num = Math.min(Math.max(num, range[0]), range[1]);
      num2 = num2 + rgen();
      num2 = Math.min(Math.max(num2, range[0]), range[1]);
    }
    return data;
  }
var data = createRandomData(600,[1000,1000000])

class TimeSeriesChart extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
 
  componentDidMount(){
    var chart = window.d3_timeseries()
    .addSerie(data,{x:'date',y:'n'}, {interpolate:'step-before'})
    .addSerie(null,{x:'date',y:'n2'}, {interpolate:'linear'})
    .xscale.tickFormat(frenchTimeFormat)
    .margin.left(70)
    .width(800);
    console.log(typeof chart)
    chart('#ts-chart-id')
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div id={'ts-chart-id'}></div>
    );
 }
 
}
export default TimeSeriesChart;
```

3. Then add the 'TimeSeriesChart' component, in the place you like to add. Eg:

```
...
import TimeSeriesChart from 'path/to/above/file'
...
return (
...
    <TimeSeriesChart/>
...
);
...
```

I am also new to React. So there may be terminology issue (but the code works). Anyway, sincerely hope this will hope someone to save time and he/she does not have to go through the trouble I went.

Cheers.